# .NET MauiBlazor Hybrid - {Appname}.Styles.css

Tags: blazor, maui

Basically, if you have an app called 'abc', then your project references a css stylesheet as follows.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <title>gMIS Mobile</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    **<link href="abc.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />**
</head>

<body>

    <div class="status-bar-safe-area"></div>

    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js" autostart="false"></script>

</body>

</html>`
```

This css file doesn't actually exists anywhere it seems, and is dynamically created. Does anybody have any idea where this is generated from and how to customize the content?

Tried to see what the content of the file is in dev tools (F12). Then to do a search in the project, using some of that words in that dynamically created css content. You can see it in dev tools, and you can pluck something out to search using, but I have had no joy searching for those words in the main project.

Comment: I found a known issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35195. You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a file called MainLayout.razor.css in the Shared folder. This should contain the main styles listed in {Appname}.styles.css.
Other styles will come from razor component specific style sheets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0